# how to check if 2 tries at random number are the same?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out an if statement that will allow me to check whatever the current (Math.floor(Math.random()*5) gave me the same value as the previous attempt? I know I can get It to print it out but is there some way of getting the system to check?

Comment: Can we see the code you're referring to?

Comment: So store it and check.....

Comment: Just use a variable `prev_val` to store previous value and compare it with current value

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your previous value and optionally your current value to variables and compare. e.g.:

Given:

```
function randomInteger(limit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}
```

You can store both to variables and compare:

```
var previousValue = randomInteger(5);
var currentValue = randomInteger(5);
if (currentValue === previousValue) {
    /* your conditional code here */
}
```

Or you can skip storing the current value to a variable and compare the new value directly:

```
if (randomInteger(5) === previousValue) {
    /* your conditional code here */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply check this boolean:
`Math.floor(Math.random()*5) === Math.floor(Math.random()*5)`